# JavaFX event triggered by time value triggers multiple times

Tags: java, javafx

I am relatively new to programming, and to help myself I am making a personal project.
I am using Javafx to build drum machine, which allowing the user to program a sequence of beats.

I have constructed sets of rows which each will function as a programmable beat sequencer for each corresponding instrument, with each row consisting of 16 buttons. if that button is pressed, the button is activated, and it will produce the instrument's sound when the loop passes through that point.

for reference this piece of kit is similar to what i wish to construct :

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81RctDCP38L._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Each button is assigned to a hashmap; the Key is an integer from 0-16, while the value is the button's characteristics itself.

The drum machine loops after 4 bars/ 16 buttons.

To trigger the event and to cause the instrument to play, the time (as a fraction of all buttons/16) will match the key of a button. once this occurs, the sound plays. the method to do this is below:

```
   public void beatState(Button button, String filename) {
    EventHandler handler = new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            soundGeneration sound = new soundGeneration(filename);

            // if the corresponding buttons key (on a range of 0-16) matches the time as a fraction (0-16)
            // and if the button text is on (activated by clicking the pad)
            if (button.equals(map.get(time.timeToFraction())) & button.getText().equals("On")) {

                // plays the file
                sound.play();

                // when duration of animation is set lower the filename prints more frequently
                // or sometimes not printed/sound played when the duration is higher
                System.out.println(filename);
            }

        }
    };
    // as i increase the duration of the animation , the program becomes both slower but returns
    // both the sound file and prints the filename more often
    Timeline animationButton = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), handler));
    animationButton.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animationButton.play();
}
```

I'll next provide the time element:

```
       public Integer timeToFraction(){
    labelFormat();
        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // time elapsed since program execution
                double elapsedMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                // converts to long
                // multiplies the value to privide a fraction
                long numerator =  (long) ((elapsedMillis/1000)*8.33);


                // value below denominates the time it takes to travel 4 beats at 125 beats per minute
                double denominator = 1.92;
                // converts below to show as a fraction
                long denominatorToBeat =(long) Math.round(denominator * 8.3);

                    // if the elapsed time raises over 16
                    // resets numerator
                    if (numerator> denominatorToBeat) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        elapsedMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                    }
                    // converts from long to to allow for hashmap matching against button position
                    fractionTime = (int) numerator;
            }
        }.start();
        return fractionTime;
    }
```

When the values match up the beat plays, achieving my aim; however, it plays multiple times, and irregular in relation to the beat.
I assume that the  animation timer repeat value in milliseconds is what causes this; I decrease it, there are more unwanted repeated sounds. I increase it and notes sometimes are not counted due to the animation passing over the value before it triggers.

I want the code to trigger the sound file when it passes over the button, more specifically when the Integer value of the hashmap the button corresponds to matches the time fraction.

I have spent hours researching and reading the documentation and for an easy problem it is becoming incredibly difficult to work around. Given that this project is seen in a multitude of portfolios and music development software i am sure there is a simple fix to my issue.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure I fully understood the requirement. Basically are you trying to loop over 16 toggle buttons and check if they are pressed or not ? For more help post [mre]  (no need for 16 buttons for the mre. 3 will do)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach in general is wrong, as you are abusing animation timers to do something not related to the GUI. You have to decouple the logic from the GUI.

I.e. The object which controls the timing and playing the sounds should have nothing to do with the buttons or any GUI. It should have some methods to set / clear a sound at particular interval, and then expose its state using properties, e.g. an ObjectProperty with some class describing the current tones being played.

The buttons should call the methods to set / clear tones, and you can add a change listener to the ObjectProperty to update the buttons appearance based on the state.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Removed the connection with the gui and went in a different direction - used the sleep function and multithreading to each instrument and now works perfectly with no issues. Thanks a lot